# Extracting data from a html file (R and regular expressions)

Tags: regex, r, string

I would like to extract data from a HTML file in R. I have a big file with this structure:

```
a <-  "</span>Cabildo \t456\t386\t70\t21\t4\t101\t36\t12\t88\t48\t84\t62\t-</p></td></tr><tr><td colspan=\"14\" bgcolor=\"#CCDDE7\"><p class=\"s3\" style=\"padding-top: 1pt;padding-left: 5pt;text-indent: 0pt;text-align: left;\"><span style=\" color: black; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;\"></span>Sierra Gorda\t106 \t89 \t17 \t-\t-\t26 \t9 \t8 \t15 \t10 \t18 \t20 \t-</p>"
```

Here an example of the file: http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/18116710/file.htm

I want to extract all the lines with this pattern:

```
</span>Cabildo \t456\t386\t70\t21\t4\t101\t36\t12\t88\t48\t84\t62\t-</p>
```

so that to get a database such as:

```
Cabildo      456 386 70 21  4 101 36 12 88 48 62 -
Sierra Gorda 106  89 17  -  -  26  9  8 15 10 20 -
...
```

"-" means missing (NA). I have been playing with str_extract function without any results (I am very new with regular expressions).

My idea is to get what is between  `</span>` and `</p>` and then to read the lines using read.csv (with tab delimiters), but maybe that is not the best way to do it because other things could be between those tags.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You should try some features related to `XPath`. See `xpathApply` or `xpathSApply` in package `XML`.

Comment: If at all possible, I would used a different language for parsing your HTML file and formatting the lines you need into a new file that is more R friendly. R is fantastic for working with data, but not so much at parsing HTML. In my opinion, Perl would be a good choice for this task as it is particularly good at reading files and parsing strings for patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you an idea of what to do -

```
# break the string at each occurrence of </span> or </p>
b <- unlist(strsplit(a,"</span>|</p>"))
# removing the first element, which is just a blank
b <- b[-1]

# remove unneeded elements by looking for the </td> tag and filtering them out, this logic can be changed depending on how the complete dataset looks
c <- grep(x = b, pattern =  "</td>", invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)

# breaking each string b/w </span> and </p> into individual columns, split by '/t'
d <- (strsplit(c,"\t"))

# appending all rows together to get one dataset
e <- data.frame(do.call(rbind,d))
```

Output -

```
> e
            X1   X2  X3  X4 X5 X6  X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14
1     Cabildo   456 386  70 21  4 101 36 12  88  48  84  62   -
2 Sierra Gorda 106  89  17   -  - 26  9  8  15  10  18  20    -
```

Comment: Thanks very much, it looks pretty nice! Because it is a huge file, breaking the string at each occurrence of </span> or </p> generate a lot of lines that are not useful, such as: "<p style=\"text-indent: 0pt;line-height: 10pt;text-align: left;\"><br/>". I will update my example to show that possible problem. I didn't think about it before :(, thanks again!!!

Comment: @sdaza, you could use `gsub` to strip out  the "<p style ... >" parts of your html file before passing it to this function. Something along these lines - `a <- gsub(x = a,"</p>.*</span", replacement = "")`. If you share more data, I could try.

Comment: I added more data (file.htm):  http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/18116710/file.htm Thank you!

Comment: After using your code: `b <- unlist(strsplit(a,"</span>|</p>"))`, I selected the rows with data using: `c <- grep(x=b, pattern='(^[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)(.*)(\t[0-9]+)', value=TRUE)`. Thank you again!

Comment: Oh okay, I thought you meant that while creating `b` you wanted those extra rows filtered out. Great that you worked it out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of this html files you might want to look at this package:
http://www.rexamine.com/resources/stringi/

It has faster implementations of regex functions than stringr package.
To install this package simply run:

```
source('http://static.rexamine.com/packages/stringi_install.R')
```

Example:

```
stri_split_regex(a, "</span>|</p>")
```